# In OCaml, how to create a float from a byte array?

Tags: floating-point, ocaml

How can I perform something similar to this C trick to obtain an OCaml `float` from a byte array?

```
union {
  double d;
  int i[2];
} u;

u.i[0] = 0;
u.i[1] = -20000000; // u.d = -0x1.ed3p+1005
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `Int64.float_of_bits` function in the standard library: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Int64.html#VALfloat_of_bits.  `Int64.bits_of_float` provides the inverse functionality.

You would need to pack the bytes into the `Int64.t` value in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `Marshal.from_bytes`. But there are no guarantees about what you get if you pass a value that doesn't come from `Marshal.to_bytes`. The C code suffers from a similar problem, of course. The meaning isn't defined (though people use it anyway).

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal code example? `let b = Bytes.make 4 (Char.chr 0) in Marshal.from_bytes b 0;;` fails with `Exception: Invalid_argument "Marshal.from_bytes"`. As you mentioned, there is probably no guarantee that this will work, so I think that @hcarty's solution ends up being a better choice, even though it does not use an array directly.

Comment: I was going to, but then I saw that there's a much better answer from @hcarty. You should definitely avoid using the `Marshal` module in a non-kosher way if at all possible.